# How do you create a nested object form in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, controller

I'm building a simple Rails-based travel app for a school project.

I want to make a form that enables the user to enter data such as the name of their Trip, two destinations, and each destination will have a location.

How can I do this with a triple nest form?

I'm very confused by the build method right now. Below is the def new method and the private methods in the controller.

```
class TripsController < ApplicationController
    def new
      @trip = Trip.new
      Destination.all.each do |destination|
        @trip.destinations.build.location
    end

  private

  def set_trip
    @trip = Trip.find(params[:id])
  end

  def trip_params
    params.require(:trip).permit(:name, :start_date, :end_date, 
      :destination_1, :destination_2, :user_id, :destinations_attributes => [:name,
      :locations_attributes => [:name]
  ]
)
```

Comment: Please show your models relations

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a big topic... It would be easier for people to help you if you shared some more of your code.

Comment: I would do one small thing at a time. 

Get your trip working first. Can you create, edit, and view a Trip? I do not see enough controller methods (like create).

The code above looks incorrect -- especially the `Destination.all` part!! 

(Think what that is doing. Every new Trip object will get every existing Destination in the database. Probably not what you want.)

Answer (score 0):

Google pretty much answers this.

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/rails-nested-forms-in-three-steps-5580f0ad0e

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

You are looking for `fields_for`